# django forms save() got an unexpected keyword argument?

Tags: python, django

In my view:

```
image = simple_image_form.save(quiet=True)
```

my form:

```
class SimpleImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ("image",)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
        super(SimpleImageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs["commit"]=False
        obj = super(SimpleImageForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.request and self.request.user:
            obj.member = self.request.user.get_current_member()
            obj.save(*args, **kwargs)
        return obj
```

when I save, I get the error:

```
save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'quiet'
```

I thought by placing **kwargs as a parameter, this wouldn't happen.  What am I doing wrong?

Note: quiet is a parameter in the obj.save function used in condition checks, but is neither an attribute of the form or the obj itself

Comment: how is your view defined? and what are you using `quiet` for ?

Comment: I'm struggling to find out where on earth your save method needs `quiet` to work :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your override may handle the `kwarg` but you shouldn't do the same with the `super` call:

```
obj = super(SimpleImageForm, self).save(commit=False)
```

That should do. This happens because the `ModelForm`'s `save` method signature is:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
```

So it doesn't match the way you're calling it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This makes sense, just took a look at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a field called `quiet` in order to save a value to that field. I don't see any reference to such a field in the form, so I'm guessing there isn't one in the model. Even if there is, you probably have to say reference it in the form since you're defining what parts of the model you're working with.